# Connecting to a multiple databases using hibernate catalog

Tags: hibernate, postgresql-9.1, catalog

I am working on an application where it requires to connect to two Postgres databases using hibernate. The details have been given below :-

**Software Details** :- Java 1.6, Hibernate 4.1.0, Postgres 9.1.

**Problem Scenario** :-The application needs to connect to two databases TEDA and TEMET on my localhost on the run-time and perform basic CRUD operations (for the initial phase).

**Approaches Tried** :- 
 1. Added the *catalog* attribute to the `<class>` tag of the hibernate mapping file. **But it did not work**. The catalog was being fetched as null always. 
 2. Create two different data sources and session factories in my Hibernate context and use them in different DAO objects. ***This approach worked for me and I was able to connect to different databases.***

**Problem Statement and references** :- I am looking for a way where the 'catalog' approach mentioned in point (1) may work.

I searched stack-overflow and other forums like
[Connect to multiple databases in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708176/connect-to-multiple-databases-in-hibernate)
and 
[what is "catalog" used in hibernate annotated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246949/what-is-catalog-used-in-hibernate-annotated-class), but most of them had a discussion on the approach (2) that uses multiple data sources.
I also had a look in the [hibernate community documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) in the section 5.1.3, point 6 which *does* mention that the catalog attribute overrides the database name in the db Url, but may be I am missing something here.

Please assist. The properties file and hibernate mapping file that I had modified are given below.

The properties file -

```
driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
urlDB=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/TEDA    
username=****
password=****
dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

The hibernate mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="somepackage.PartnerPoc" catalog="TEMET" table="partner_poc">
  <!-- Table specific hibernate implementation and HQL queries-->
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Please let me know if you need any more information from my end.

Thanks in advance.